# include() fails after conversion to Plesk server

Tags: php

I just switched a database over to a Plesk server on GoDaddy. Now, my connection script include fails with this error:

> PHP Warning:  include(/rev/scripts/connection.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\rev\db_administration\complete_backup.php
>   on line 5 PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening
>   '/rev/scripts/connection.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;.\includes;.\pear')

I'm not sure why it is prepending 'G:\PleskVhosts\' to the url or even if this is what is crashing it. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? This code has worked for a long time, so I don't know why it needs to change with the new server.

What is strange to me is that if I run this from a browser (including the edit below), it works. But I need this to run from scheduled tasks, and there is where I get the error.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $connection = $path . '/rev/scripts/connection.php';
    include ($connection);

    echo "success";
?>
```

EDIT: Per suggestion below, I changed my code to this, which allows it run from the browser. But I still can't get it to run from scheduled tasks:

```
$path = !empty($_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ? $_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT'] : $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: include path is wrong

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see what you mean. How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the include path in your error message `... include(/rev/scripts/connection.php) ...`, it looks like `$path` is an empty string. A bit of googling shows that GoDaddy doesn't always translate `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` correctly for some of its add-on domains and subdomains. Try replace `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with `$_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`.

So essentially adding,

```
$path = !empty($_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ? $_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT'] : $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

or

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__); // this might or might not work.
```

**UPDATE**

`$_SERVER` won't work when attempting to run this from a scheduled task (presumably, via `cron`). Try this:

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', substr(str_replace(pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME), '', __FILE__), 0, -1));
```

It's supposed to get you the same data as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for cron jobs.

Comment: @usr55410 Glad it works. Can I get an upvote too, please? :) Thanks!

Comment: OK, this is weird. When I run the script from a browser, it works. But I need to run this from their scheduled tasks. When I call it from there, I get these same errors. Any ideas?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Something is strange with how their server paths work.

Comment: Assuming you are running the scheduled task outside of a web server, say using `cron`, it makes sense that `$_SERVER` isn't set because there is no server.

Comment: I agree. I solved it by just using relative paths. In this situation, I think that it's the only way to make it work. Thanks for your help.